# Errors opening PPTX in PowerPoint 2011 Mac

Tags: powerpoint

When I try to open a PPTX file in PowerPoint 2011, I get "There was an error accessing ". This is a known good file, it opens on another mac just fine.

Comment: This is a question for http://apple.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Try opening the PPTX with OpenOffice...

2) Look other ways here: http://forums.techguy.org/business-applications/1129888-powerpoint-file-crashes-powerpoint-upon.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the powerpoint presentation requires an external resource, such as a video or picture, and that resource is missing on the mac the powerpoint file is being transferred to. Try to put all the files from your presentation in a single folder and copy the folder to the other computer.